# Do we have to define one-to-many relationship natively in a db if we use @OneToMany annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm using hibernate 3.3.1 along with PostgreSQL 9.3 and I've written the following mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player_account")
public class PlayerAccount {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Player.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="player_id")
    private Player player;
    //GET, SET methods
}
```

The question is do we actual have to specify that many-to-one raltionship in the database when we're creating a table? I mean to define a references in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE player_account (
  SERIAL UNIQUE,
  player_id integer REFERENCES players
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to define in database; but that foreign key column should be present in table. i.e. player_id should be present in player_account table.